# 2px + p = (12 − p)x + 1 polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have a problem with $2px + p = (12 − p)x + 1$

I don't know what $p$ must be in order to solve the equation with  $x = -1/2$

So far I tried this:

```
2px + p = 12x - px + 1
3px + p = 12x + 1
x = -1/2
3p(-1/2) + p = 12(-1/2) + 1
-1,5 p + p = -6 + 1
-0,5p = -5
p = 10
```

But it it should be $p = 14/5$, how?

Comment: With the facts as you have stated them, your answer is correct. You get 14/5 for p when x = 1/2.

Comment: @PaulSundheim but I dont understand how to calculate it

Comment: You calculated p correctly, so you are saying you don't know how to calculate x?  Or are you saying you used a program to calculate p, but you don't know how to calculate p by yourself?

Comment: A somewhat different presentation: from $3px + p = 12x + 1 \ \iff \ p*(3x+1)=12x+1$, one deduces that $p=\dfrac{12x+1}{3x+1}$ in which you can replace $x$ by $-1/2$. There is a **problem of naming** : $p$ is not a polynomial, but a ratio of two polynomials, also called a rational fraction.